# transfer field from point cloud to mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, point-clouds

I want to transfer float attributes/field from this point cloud, with this float attributes distribution.

[image]

To this mesh, where vertices of the mesh have the same count/position as point cloud.
If I use Sample nearest/Sample index, it outputs this mess.

[image]

First I thought there are duplicated points in the point cloud, but no, all are individuals.
Indices arrangement is different in both cases, but that shouldn't matter if I sample nearest?
Do you know what is wrong and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: you didn't even show us your whole (important) node tree...so maybe you wanna share a blend file so we can check it out instead of asking questions in the comments....?

Answer (score 0):

So I got an answer from StrayBillie on [Blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/curvature-gn-issue-how-to-correctly-transfer-float-field-from-point-cloud-to-mesh/1474168/2?u=jlbohm), its totally rookie mistake. Sample nodes need to be plugged correctly, both geometry inputs coming from point cloud.

Here is updated [Blend file](https://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=japylldW%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.com/b/japylldW/))

[image]